# Chrome extension: Click Event Listener won't initiate

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-events

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I have an error that gets returned whenever I try to add a "click" event to a class.

> Error in event handler for 'undefined': Object #<NodeList> has no method 'addEventListener' TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'addEventListener'

Here's my code for the function (popup.js):

```
listElements: function(elements) {
    iHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        ...
        ...
        iHTML += '<div class="theBtn">btn</div>';
        ...
        ...
    }

    $('popup_content').innerHTML = iHTML;

    var btnElements = document.getElementsByClassName('theBtn');
    if (btnElements.length > 0) {
        btnElements.addEventListener("click", clicked);
    }
}
```

I also tried `each()` and that didn't work either. Same error message. It logs `btnElements` perfectly fine too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery instead of

```
var btnElements = document.getElementsByClassName('theBtn');
if (btnElements.length > 0) {
    btnElements.addEventListener("click", clicked);
}
```

subscribe to click event as:

```
$('.theBtn').click(clicked);
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns NodeList, and you can't attach event to it as `btnElements.addEventListener`. However this should work:

```
var btnElements = document.getElementsByClassName('theBtn');
for (var i = btnElements.length; i--;) {
    btnElements[i].addEventListener("click", clicked);
}
```

Comment: Didn't even think of that... That worked wonderfully, thank you!